# My code for some reason shows NaN instead of number

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting `NaN` instead of number when I click the button `#plr1button1`?
Like I don't understand it I am looking at it for like 2 hours and I still can't figure out the mistake.

```
class Fighter {
    constructor(atk, def, hp) {
        this.atk = atk;
        this.def = def;
        this.hp = hp;
    }
}
var Fighter1 = new Fighter(40, 5, 100);
var Fighter2 = new Fighter(30, 20, 100);
Fighter1.attack = function() {
    var attack1 = this.atk + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 5) - Fighter2.def;
    Fighter2.hp = Fighter2.hp - attack1;
    document.getElementById("hp2").innerHTML = Fighter2.hp;
}
Fighter2.attack = function() {
    var attack1 = this.atk + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 5) - Fighter1.def;
    Fighter1.hp = Fighter1.hp - attack1;
    document.getElementById("hp1").innerHTML = Fighter1.hp;
}
function random() {
    var randomNum =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    /*var randomNum2 =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var randomNum3 =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;*/
    if (randomNum === 1) {
        document.getElementById("plr1button1").innerHTML = "Attack";
        $("#plr1button1").bind("click", Fighter1.attack);
        document.getElementById("plr2button1").innerHTML = "Attack";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lose the context with that event handler; use `.bind` to fix it.

```
$("#plr1button1").bind("click", Fighter1.attack.bind(Fighter1));
```

It's easy to detect it: just put the breakpoint into `attack` method and check what's `this` equal to when the method is called by as `click` event handler.

---

There are several other issues with your code.

First, you can easily abstract a function that generates a random integer number in the given range - and reuse it instead of repeating the whole `Math.floor(Math.random...` snippet.

Second, you mixed two concerns in your `attack` code, changing both state (of attacked Fighter) and its representation. It's usually better to separate those.

Finally, you unnecessarily hardcoded all the actions in two Fighter instance - instead of using `prototype` to store a single function.

For example, there's one way how this can be simplified:

```
class Fighter {
    constructor(atk, def, hp) {
        this.atk = atk;
        this.def = def;
        this.hp = hp;
    }

    attack(enemy) {
        const hits = this.atk + _randomInRange(0, 5) - enemy.def;
        enemy.hp -= hits;
        enemy.render();
    }

    render() {
        // updates the representation of Fighter
    }
}

function _randomInRange(from, to) {
  return from + Math.floor( Math.random() * (to + 1 - from) );
}
```

And here's a [small (and incomplete) demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2vdt19c6/) of that approach in action.

Answer (score 1):

It's because how you are calling it, `this` is not `Fighter1`, it's the element that triggered the event (since you're using jQuery; vanilla JS it would be the event object) inside of `Fighter1.attack`.

When you call a function directly like you are, it's going to use the function but won't maintain it's usual context. I.e., `Fighter1.attack` in a callback is not the same as `Fighter1.attack()`.

What you need to do is bind the functions to their respective `this` so they maintain that inside.

Change your callback like this:

```
$("#plr1button1").bind("click", Fighter1.attack.bind(Fighter1));
```

Then, when it's triggered, `this` will be `Fighter1` as you intended.

You could also bind the function overall to not have to rebind:

```
Fighter1.attack = (function() {
    var attack1 = this.atk + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 5) - Fighter2.def;
    Fighter2.hp = Fighter2.hp - attack1;
    document.getElementById("hp2").innerHTML = Fighter2.hp;
}).bind(Fighter1);
```

Repeat for `Fighter2` as well.

Comment: *"this is nothing"* isn't really correct...in OP code is the element

Comment: I misspoke...it is the element returned by jQuery

Comment: Good catch again. I've updated again and made mention of both scenarios. ;)